# Django - filtering out already rated restaurants in yelp like app

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider the following database model:

```
class User:
    id         = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant:
    id    = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Rating:
    id             = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    by_user        = models.ForeignKey(to='User',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       related_name='written_ratings')
    for_restaurant = models.ForeignKey(to='Restaurant',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       related_name='received_ratings')
    score          = models.SmallIntegerField() 

    # make sure only one vote per user per restaurant
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('by_user', 'for_restaurant')
```

For a given `User`, we can obtain a list of `Restaurant` that we have not yet rated by performing the following query (that I have learned from [my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872910/django-performance-with-not-in-filter-with-giant-list))

```
eligible_restaurants = Restaurant.objects.exclude(rating__by_user_id=my_id)
```

But what happens when the `Ratings` don't point directly at the `Restaurants` - but rather at an intermediate `Profile` object?

```
class User:
    id         = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Restaurant:
    id              = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    current_profile = models.OneToOneField(to='Profile',
                                           on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                           related_name='+')
    # the `+` means to not generate a related name

class Profile:
    # this is here acting as an intermediate between
    # `Restaurant` and `Rating` so that we can keep track
    # of all reviews - deleting/remaking would simply be
    # creating a new `Profile` and setting the `Restaurant`
    # to point to it instead - the old one will act as a
    # historical record
    id            = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    by_restaurant = models.ForeignKey(to='Restaurant',
                                      on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                      related_name='written_profiles')
    picture_url   = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    picture_desc  = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Rating:
    id             = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    by_user        = models.ForeignKey(to='User',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       related_name='written_ratings')
    for_profile    = models.ForeignKey(to='Profile',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       related_name='received_ratings')
    score          = models.SmallIntegerField()

    # make sure only one vote per user per restaurant
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('by_user', 'for_profile')
```

How would I query for eligible restaurants now?

Comment: The you query for the Profiles and get the Restaurant from them. BTW your classes have to inherit from Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter them starting with restaurants

```
restaurant_ids = Rating.objects.filter(by_user=user).values_list('for_profile__by_restaurant', flat=True).distinct()
eligible_restaurants = Restaurant.objects.exclude(id__in=restaurant_ids)
```

**Note**: this will generate only one query because django's querysets are lazy.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. As a rookie to django - do you have any recommendations on MySQL/database django benchmarking? Any handy tools to help me test the speed of these queries when the dataset gets large (~100k)?

Comment: @Alan I would recommend using https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar for starters, then it really depends what profiling you are trying to do.